# How to login a website using python module "mechanize" with a cookies.txt exported by the chrome extension "cookies.txt export"?

Tags: python, cookies, google-chrome-extension, mechanize

I have looked through similar questions in stackoverflow yet seemingly no answers measures up. Now I have a cookies.txt in hands which is exported by a chrome extension named "cookies.txt". I can execute a command "wget --load-cookies cookies.txt www.example.com" to download the webpage with the account authenticated.

However, I met a problem when I tried to use this file in my python script as follows,

```
import mechanize

cookie = 'cookies.txt'

cookiejar = mechanize.FileCookieJar(cookies.txt)

br = mechanize.Browser()

br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)

url = 'www.example.com'
response = br.open(url)
s = response.read()

f = open('test.html','w')
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

I only got a webpage without my account logged in after executing this script. And If I change the first several lines of code into this

```
import mechanize

cookie = 'cookies.txt'
cookiejar = mechanize.MozillaCookieJar()
cookiejar.load(cookie)
```

I got an error message "mechanize._clientcookie.LoadError: cookies.txt does not look like a Netscape format cookies file" executing the script.

I have no idea how I can get the authentication done with this cookies.txt given that this file works in wget command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same error until I added this to the top of my cookie file, and now works.

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the mechanize source code, the load method of class MozillaCookieJar will search for the regexp "#( Netscape)? HTTP Cookie File" first, so you can insert this line into the top of the exported cookie.txt:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the cookielib module to handle the cookies.

http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html

Specifically, you need to read up on how to use FileCookieJar.load()

That should get you on track.